# Multiple Database Django

Tags: django

I need to connect my app to multiple database, but I'm not having any success.

After I've defined my databases in settings.py, what do I have to do?
I don't know if I did the right thing, but I created a routers.py and added the following code:

```
class DBRouter(object):
     """A router to control all database operations on models in
     the contrib.auth application"""

     def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
         if hasattr(model,'teste'):
            return model.connection_name
         return None

     def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if hasattr(model,'teste'):
            return model.connection_name
        return None

     def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if hasattr(model,'teste'):
            return model.connection_name == db
        return db == 'default'
```

Do I have to do a syncdb? What do I have to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the `DATABASE_ROUTERS` setting?

Make sure you also carefully read the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/, especially the part describing potential drawbacks/limitations coming from the usage of multiple databases (eg. you will *not* be able to do cross-database joins)

Comment: I did, when I'm about to save the data on the other DB, I get the following error:

Field '' doesn't have a default value

Comment: hm.. this doesn't look like a multi-db related issue; it seems much more something related to your model.. could you post your model code?